# Can I keep iBatis and Mybatis in the same application while switching to myBatis?

Tags: java, conflict, ibatis, mybatis

The question is the one of the title. There follows a brief explanation.

I have an application which uses iBatis 2 and I would like to migrate to the latest version of myBatis (3.2.0 at the momento of writing). Since I don't have enough time to start and finish the work without having to do other tasks on that application, and considering that creating a branch would require a painful merge at the end, I was wondering if I can introduce myBatis and then meet my goal gradually. In the end iBatis would be removed entirely.

Can I encounter some conflicts on the way? In other words, can iBatis 2.3 and MyBatis 3.2 live together? Maybe some of you faced the same problem.

Comment: Do ibatis/mybatis use the same package and class names? If yes, then they cannot live together, but porting will be easy.

Comment: So you are saying that the only problem _is_ a collision between package names. Are you sure that it is just that?

Answer (score 2):

I think the migration process is not very complicated at all, it is a task you can achieve in a few hours.

Most of the work is in changing packages names. Take a look to this [doc](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/wiki/DocUpgrade3).

Anyway, since iBatis and myBatis use different packages should not be any problem to work with them at the same time.

Comment: I feel that I'm on your side, but I think that some one shares the same fear of me: this is a production environment, it's already stressing, I don't want to make it even more stressing. This would be an "under the hoods" intervention completed in the time digged between activities. So, if possible, I would like to keep iBatis and MyBatis together for the time necessary for the switch. I was wondering for an extensive answer, e.g. exploring all the possible conflict points, so it would be useful and one can say "ok, let's start". I think package names claim it's among the most important.